# How to get connection name from Entity in Symfony3?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm trying to build API. I use FosRestbundle and jmsserializerbundle.

I have two database connections, entities are the same, but data in databases are different. I have folowing method in controller:

```
public function getTimesAllAction()
{
    $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Time', 'conn2')->findAll();
    $view = $this->view($data, 200);
    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

AppBundle::Time is:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="times")
 * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
 */
class Time
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="timeno")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $time_no;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250, name="timename")
     */
    protected $time_name;
}
```

I need to add one more property type, that point to connection name

How can I get connetction name from Entity?

Comment: May be just to add an entity attribute that will specify the connection name?

Comment: @Timurib, yes, it is. but if I use multiply connections with one entity how to do it?

Comment: Every entity object managed by some Entity Manager. Every Entity Manager works through own DBAL connection. http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: @Timurib ok, but I can use entity by this way: $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Time', 'conn2')->findAll(); or $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Time', 'conn1')->findAll();

Comment: Sorry, i cann't understand the question. Your code is ok, only second argument of `getRepository()` should be an entity manager name, not connection (if their names are not same).

Comment: thanks! That's mean, that I need get entity manager's name inside entity. It's bed practice =(